# Filtering mentions in react-draft-wysiwyg editor

Tags: javascript, mention, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am trying to implement mentions with react-draft-wysiwyg editor. But the functionality to filter the suggestions is not working as expected. Apparently there is no event which gets triggered specifically as the value is typed after trigger symbol. Has anyone implemented it or am I missing out on something?

I am getting the list of suggestions and those are appearing as I type the trigger. But the letters I type after trigger, are not filtering out the suggestions.